# Response data is not in valid format in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, character-encoding, shift-jis

I have a text file with the character set as "Shift_JIS" and the file contains Japanese characters. And then I do ajax request to that file as shown below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "demo.txt",
    success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }}
);
```

But the data that is shown in alert is not valid Japanese character. Instead it shows some junk data. Even though I tried to set the response header character set and I do many of the solution that is already before in stackoverflow, But it didn't work. Can any one help me to solve this ?

Note: Browser is Internet Explorer

Comment: Try to console log it? Or maybe try to visit yourhost/demo.txt and see how the text looks?

Comment: can you share some shift_jis letter from demo.txt (update question)

Comment: @DavidJorHpan インフォメーションコード

Comment: @MehulMohan It is not problem with text. I set the character set as UTF8. At that time it properly worked. But with "Shift_JIS" only it makes problem

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried to change the charset, have you tried changing the contentType to plain text ?  :

```
$.ajax({
    /*...*/
    contentType: "text/plain; charset=Shift_JIS"
    /*...*/
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read a Shift_JIS file into a string object directly in JavaScript. You have to once store the content of the file into a binary object and then decode it into UTF-16 (the internal representation of JavaScript string) with `TextDecoder`.

Unfortunately, jQuery's `$.ajax()` cannot handle the response body as binary (`dataType: 'binary'`) out of the box. So you have to use additional module like
[jQuery BinaryTransport](https://github.com/henrya/js-jquery/tree/master/BinaryTransport), or use XMLHttpRequest like this:

```js
// ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "demo.txt", true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer"; // handle response body as binary
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
  if (oReq.response) {
    var sjisDecoder = new TextDecoder('shift-jis');
    alert(sjisDecoder.decode(oReq.response))  // Note: not oReq.responseText
  }
};
oReq.send(null);
```